# Validation accuracy increases then suddenly decreases

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, glove

I am training an LSTM model on the [SemEval 2017 task 4A dataset](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task4/index.php?id=data-and-tools). I observe that first validation accuracy increases along with training accuracy but then suddenly decreases by a significant amount. The loss decreases but validation loss increases by a signifcant amount.

[image: The training sample]

Here is the code of my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

And here is the model summary

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 300, 30)           60000     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 300, 30)           120       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 300, 30)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 64)                16128     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 64)                256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 76,569
Trainable params: 76,381
Non-trainable params: 188
```

I am using GloVe for word embeddings, Adam optimizer, Binary Crossentropy loss function.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few choices:

1. keep training and see what happens
2. if the val_loss become worse, you're overfitting -- check out how to deal with that -- increase the amount of the data, make a simpler network or do whatever seems to work in your particular case.
3. if the val_loss gets better back again, you're on the right path.

And, yeah, share results with us, what happens if you run training for a couple more epochs?

Comment: I trained them for 20 epochs and what I observed was that validation accuracy went up but later it came down and then after 3-4 epochs rose. Same with validation loss, it decreased and then increased. It's going like a sinusoidal wave.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same. Even shuffling the dataset does not help. Even the accuracy of the model decreases while training. I could not figure out the exact cause. If anyone knows please share it..